# Eager fetch property in Mapped Super class

Tags: spring, hibernate, hql

Our Mapped Super class has createdBy column which is defined to be lazily loaded

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {
    @CreatedBy
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @XmlTransient
    @JoinColumn(name = "created_by", updatable = false, columnDefinition = "bigint")
    protected User createdBy;

   public User getCreatedBy() {
      return createdBy;
   }

   public void setCreatedBy(User createdBy) {
      this.createdBy = createdBy;
   }
```

I need to load this property eagerly in one of the sub class that inherits this aforementioned class.

```
@Override
@XmlElement(name = "createdBy")
@JsonProperty("createdBy")
public User getCreatedBy() {
    return super.getCreatedBy();
}
```

How can I do that?

I tried the following (used NamedEntityGraph and HQL), but, both did not return createdBy from MappedSuperClass that is defined as lazy

```
//defined at the top of Model
@NamedEntityGraphs({
        // eagerly fetches created by and program names when used
        @NamedEntityGraph(
                name = "graphWithCreatedBy",
                attributeNodes = {
                        @NamedAttributeNode("createdBy")
                }
        )
})

//Repository method
@EntityGraph(value = "Program.createdBy", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH) //tried both LOAD and FETCH
    Program findOne(Specification<Program> specification);
```

---Using HQL FETCH JOIN --

```
//Repository Implementation
private static final String PROGRAM_USER_QUERY = "SELECT " +
            " sp FROM Program sp " +
            " LEFT JOIN FETCH sp.createdBy where sp.id = :id";

Query query = entityManager.createQuery(PROGRAM_USER_QUERY ).
                setParameter("id", id);

query.getSingleResult();
```

Both approaches returns program, but not the createdBy User
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Good question. Would it be possible to add a default constructor that did super.getGetCreatedBy() on instantiation, hopefully forcing loading of the field? Bit of a longshot. My first reaction to the question was that I don't think you can do this and also not quite sure why you want to lazy load in the super class? is it because you have extensions that shouldn't eager load for performance? This might be worth a spin though? Interested to see how you get on/resolution for this.

Comment: @DaisyDay existing code and every table extends that superclass. So, don't want to change existing functionality. Also since every class extends superclass, even User extends that superclass and might cause infinite loop while getting User's createdBy when we are getting Program's createdBy

Comment: Ouch. Seems like a bit of a restrictive design. When you say you need to load it eagerly, you mean you want instantiation of the subclass to load this properly eagerly right? You could try 'hiding' the field and using EAGER in the subclass? Clutching at straws!

Comment: Yes, I want to load that property eagerly when loading subclass. How do you do that hiding? Could you explain with eg?

Comment: Hiding in a subclass is just naming the variable again. I have no idea whether it will work to be honest. I don't know if annotations would function as expected etc. See field hiding: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_Object_Oriented_Design/0330__Java_Inheritance_Hiding.htm